# Any way to extend Quick Look so you can copy text from it?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, plugins, quicklook

I find quick look really handy, but I know you can't copy text from files without opening them. I wonder if there is any way around this, or if it would be possible to do with a plug-in?

Comment: Oh yeah baby... let's plug it up and make quick lock stop being quick! :P

Comment: being able to grab a snippet of code/whatever quickly from a file without having to open it in a separate program would be faster on the whole system (and quicklook already has to have the text in order to display it), so i think it wouldn't be too much of a sacrifice

Comment: I hope for the same thing. That was just me teasing. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check [this tip](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/21/select-text-in-quick-look-windows/):

> #### Select Text in Quick Look Windows
>
> To activate the setting, open a Terminal window and type the following:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool TRUE;killall Finder
> ```
>
> The changes take effect immediately. To deactivate the setting, open a Terminal window and type the following:
>
> ```
> defaults delete com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection;killall Finder
> ```

It works only from Finder windows. Which I guess is what you're after.
Confirmed on Lion.

Comment: **qlmanage -r** should suffice instead of killing finder itself.

Comment: Great tip; does anyone know how to make this work on the command line, with the `qlmanage`utility's `-p` command?